# How to connect two specific clients by ID using websockets

Tags: node.js, websocket, webrtc, p2p

I created a chat system that allows you to connect to people to video chat.

The problem is, I need to connect two clients via webRTC based on an ID or something that allows me to differentiate between clients.

At the moment, the connection is random. My code simply searches for an existing candidate and connects to them.

I tried setting an ID to clients this way...

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server,
wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8080}),
CLIENTS=[];

wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
CLIENTS.push(ws);
ws.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
    sendAll(message);
});
ws.send("NEW USER JOINED");
});
```

Where `CLIENTS` will keep track of each individul client.

But still this does not solve my problem. This my client.js code...

```
window.onload = function(){    


navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
window.RTCIceCandidate = window.RTCIceCandidate || window.mozRTCIceCandidate || window.webkitRTCIceCandidate;
window.RTCSessionDescription = window.RTCSessionDescription || window.mozRTCSessionDescription || window.webkitRTCSessionDescription;
window.RTCPeerConnectionErrorCallback = window.RTCPeerConnectionErrorCallback || window.mozRTCPeerConnectionErrorCallback || window.webkitRTCPeerConnectionErrorCallback;



serverConnection = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:3434');
serverConnection.onmessage = gotMessageFromServer;


serverConnection.onmessage = gotMessageFromServer;

var constraints = {
    video: true,
    audio: false,
};

if(navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, getUserMediaSuccess, getUserMediaError);
} else {
    alert('Your browser does not support getUserMedia API');
}



}

function getUserMediaSuccess(stream) {
    localStream = stream;
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}

function getUserMediaError(error) {
    console.log(error);
}


function errorHandler(error) {
    console.log(error);
}


function start(isCaller) {

peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(peerConnectionConfig);
peerConnection.onicecandidate = gotIceCandidate;
peerConnection.onaddstream = gotRemoteStream;
peerConnection.addStream(localStream);

if(isCaller) {
    peerConnection.createOffer(gotDescription, createOfferError);
}
}

function gotDescription(description) {
    console.log('got description');
    peerConnection.setLocalDescription(description, function () {
        serverConnection.send(JSON.stringify({'sdp': description}));
    }, function() {console.log('set description error')});
}

function gotIceCandidate(event) {
    if(event.candidate != null) {
        serverConnection.send(JSON.stringify({'ice': event.candidate}));
    }
}


function gotRemoteStream(event) {
    console.log("got remote stream");
    remote.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
}

function createOfferError(error) {
    console.log(error);
}
function gotMessageFromServer(message) {
    if(!peerConnection) start(false);


    var signal = JSON.parse(message.data);
    if(signal.sdp) {
        peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(signal.sdp), function() {
        peerConnection.createAnswer(gotDescription, errorHandler);
    }, errorHandler);
} else if(signal.ice) {
    peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(signal.ice));
 }
 }
```

How can I assign clients an ID and connect them based on their IDs. For example if I have `client1` and want to connect him to `client2`, so that these two can share video with one another, how may I do that?

webRTC is incredibly difficult as a beginner, any guidance is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I am suggesting may not be the best solution, but a simple way to do it may be:

- client1 sees a list of available peers( client2 is one of them), client1 selects client2 and clicks call button,
- now on server, you can generate a random token for the call, use it as a websocket roomname and probably call id
- add client1's connection to this websocket room, forward the call request to client2
- if client2 accepts call, add client2's connection to the room
- your server can listen to peer joining room and ask broadcast that message to all peers already part of that room
- now the peers already in room( client1) can initiate a WebRTC call to the new peer( client2)